# How can I read internal file values and create directory then move file PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I need to read from a file, and based off the value in line one, move the file to the value name.

For example, if it says `type = item`, move that file to a directory I might need to create named `item`, then move on to the next files.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Sounds doable. Go for it.

Comment: I would if I wasnt new to powershell ;)

Comment: We don't write code for you. Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Im pretty sure this is close to what I need, but what I want to do is not search for a string, I want to read the vaklue of type (type=) and create, move that file to the value directory, like item.

get-childitem "<SourceFolder>" -filter 7*.txt -
recurse | select-string -list -pattern "test" | move -dest "<DestinationFolder>"

Comment: Please don't put code like that in a comment. Edit your question to add the code in a formatted manner.

Answer (score 0):

via your comment vs original post. As for this...

```
get-childitem "<SourceFolder>" -filter 7*.txt - recurse | select-string -list -pattern "test" | move -dest "<DestinationFolder>"
```

… it would never work because this returns the full filename plus the string you searched for as a collection. Thus what you are doing may require a loop and cleanup of all the random stuff.

Example - using your post comment as is and pulling out the move / recuse stuff:

```
Get-ChildItem 'd:\temp' -filter '*.txt' | 
Select-String -list -pattern 'test' | %{ $_ }

# Results

D:\temp\TestFile0.txt:1:test
D:\temp\TestFile1.txt:1:test
D:\temp\TestFile2.txt:1:test
```

So, based on the above, you can see, you are not passing a legitimate full filename down the pipe, though you are matching the string. So, you'd want to take a different approach or use what you have and cleanup the results but trimming off that unneeded stuff.

***Update as per Ansgar suggestion***

Here is one option and since, as you say, you are new, a walk thru process. Note there are always different options / methods to do this.

```
# Get the target files
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp' -filter '*.txt' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results

    Directory: D:\temp

Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name                    
----          ------------- ------ ----                    
-a----   7/6/2018  10:16 PM     24 1 passwordchangelog.txt 
-a----   7/6/2018  10:16 PM     24 10 passwordchangelog.txt
-a----   7/6/2018  10:16 PM     24 11 passwordchangelog.txt
-a----   9/4/2018   5:20 PM     26 TestFile0.txt           
-a----   9/4/2018   5:20 PM     26 TestFile1.txt           
-a----   9/4/2018   5:20 PM     26 TestFile2.txt 




# Get the target files, matching the string filter
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp' -filter '*.txt' | 
Select-String -List -Pattern 'test'

# Results

D:\temp\TestFile0.txt:1:test
D:\temp\TestFile1.txt:1:test
D:\temp\TestFile2.txt:1:test


# Get the target files, matching the string filter, clearing the meta data
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp' -filter '*.txt' | 
Select-String -list -pattern 'test') -replace (':\d.*')

# Results

D:\temp\TestFile0.txt
D:\temp\TestFile1.txt
D:\temp\TestFile2.txt


# Get the target files, matching the string filter, clearing the meta data, test direcory create and file action
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp' -filter '*.txt' | 
Select-String -list -pattern 'test') -replace (':\d.*') |
Move-Item -Destination (New-Item -Type Directory -Verbose -Force ('D:\temp\NewFiles') -WhatIf) -Verbose -WhatIf

# Results

Move-Item : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "destination" is null. Change the value of argument "destination" to a non-null value.
At line:3 char:1
+ Move-Item -dest (New-Item -Type Directory -Verbose -Force ('D:\temp\N ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand




# Get the target files, matching the string filter, clearing the meta data, force direcory create if it does not exist and execute the file action
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp' -filter '*.txt' | 
Select-String -List -Pattern 'test') -replace (':\d.*') |
Move-Item -Destination (New-Item -Type Directory -Verbose -Force ('D:\temp\NewFiles')) -Verbose -Force

# Results

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\temp\NewFiles".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\TestFile0.txt Destination: D:\temp\NewFiles\TestFile0.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\TestFile1.txt Destination: D:\temp\NewFiles\TestFile1.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\TestFile2.txt Destination: D:\temp\NewFiles\TestFile2.txt".


Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp\NewFiles' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results

    Directory: D:\temp\NewFiles

Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name         
----          ------------- ------ ----         
-a----   9/4/2018   5:20 PM     26 TestFile0.txt
-a----   9/4/2018   5:20 PM     26 TestFile1.txt
-a----   9/4/2018   5:20 PM     26 TestFile2.txt
```

Comment: You may want to add a (code) suggestion what they should do instead. Like `... | Select-String ... | Select-Object -Expand Filename | ...`.